# SVN Revert change. Reapply subsequent changes

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Sorry I couldn't think of a good way to explain it in one sentence for a title.

So what i'm wondering is the best way to structure SVN for multiple developers to work on. We have a Dev (Trunk), UAT, Release. Once a release is complete it is then tagged as a record.

Everyone either works in Dev or in a branch if the feature is large enough to warrant it. Once they have tested and are happy with their changes they then merge their changes from Dev to UAT or (branch to dev to UAT).

The issue comes when something fails in UAT. We need to be able to remove this change. We try to work on wholly separate parts of the system but this is not always possible. So sometimes we may have:

Change 1
Change 2
Change 3
Change 4

Change 1 and change 3 both affect some of the sames files. Change 1 has failed testing. We can then revert the files affected in change 1 but this will also revert the changes in change 4. Is there a way to revert everything back to change 1 and then reapply in order each subsequent change. I know we could manually remerge all changes but there may be 30 changes going in at once as it is a very large system.

I know this may cause change 4 to no longer work as it may of unintentionally depended on a change within change 1. But in the majority of cases id expect it to work.

Is this possible in an automated fashion first of all?

And second is it actually a valid working procedure?

If not is there a better way to manage multiple developers all working on the system at the same time and allowing the pulling of changesets?

Thanks

Comment: how is git related if you work in svn?

Comment: The reason that I tagged Git was that it may be a more appropriate solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only 100% reliable solution to this issue is to avoid merging features (that is not directly related upon each other) together until they have passed UAT, or even better - deployed production. This direction is known in general as [Continuous Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery). Would require shorter lead time on the UAT and strong engineering discipline around deployments.

If you are not yet ready to move to CD, then you will be eventually facing a need to revert some changes as you describe. Some VCS like git can simplify the process but won't solve the principal issue by some any of a magic.

As for the techniques in your example, you can always revert the problematic `Change 1` (merge reverse change in svn or `git revert <sha1>`). You will be notified of obvious textual conflicts by both svn and git, which you might either fix by hand or instead start with reverting the later dependent change, e.g. `git revert <Change 3>; git revert <Change 1>` in your case, with subsequent re-doing of `Change 3` anew. SCM won't be able to detect potential conflicts of higher order with `Change 4`.

Comment: I know and got some cases, when `C1 or C2` work, but `C1 and C2` - not